# TikZ line dots and trees

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, graphs

Given the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (node1)   at (-6,0)   [draw,fill=gray!30] {node1};
\node (node2)   at (-2,-1.5)    [draw] {node2};
\node (node3)   at (2,-1.5) [draw] {node3};
\node (node4)   at (6,-1.5) [draw] {node4};

\draw (node cs:name=node1,anchor=east) |- (8,0);
\draw (node cs:name=node4,anchor=north)[-*] |- (6,0);
\draw (node cs:name=node3,anchor=north)[-*] |- (2,0);
\draw (node cs:name=node2,anchor=north)[-*] |- (-2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

In the resulting picture, the dots ending the lines from `node2`, `node3` and `node4` are just below the horizontal line coming from `node1`:

[image]

1) How to place the dots so that they are vertically centered *over* the horizontal line?

2) Is it possible to realize the same graph, with exactly the same feature, but with the `trees` TikZ library, or with the `forest` package? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below shows two different options for placing the dots on the line. The first one uses a custom arrow tip (named `Midcircle`) which is similar to the `*` arrow tip you used, except that the circle is centered on the end coordinate of the path. The second option is to use a `node` to make the dot, instead of an arrow tip.

I also changed the coordinates you used a bit. The `node cs` coordinate system has an implicit form, so you can say `node1.east`, instead of `node cs:name=node1,anchor=east`.

And I defined the end of the vertical lines using a perpendicular coordinate: `(node2.north |- node1.east)`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

% define a new arrow tip, filled circle centered on the end of the path
\pgfdeclarearrow{
  name=Midcircle,
  parameters= {\the\pgfarrowlength},  
  setup code={
   \pgfarrowssettipend{0.25\pgfarrowlength}
   \pgfarrowssetlineend{-0.25\pgfarrowlength}
   \pgfarrowlinewidth=\pgflinewidth
   \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlength
  },
  drawing code={
   \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfarrowlength}{0pt}}{0.5\pgfarrowlength}
   \pgfusepathqfill
  },
  defaults = { length = 5pt }
}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  box/.style={draw}
]
\node [box,fill=gray!30] (node1) at (-6,0)    {node1};
\node [box]              (node2) at (-2,-1.5) {node2};
\node [box]              (node3) at (2,-1.5)  {node3};
\node [box]              (node4) at (6,-1.5)  {node4};

\draw               (node1.east)  -- (8,0);
\draw [-Midcircle] (node4.north) -- (node4.north |- node1.east);
\draw [-Midcircle] (node3.north) -- (node3.north |- node1.east);
\draw [-Midcircle] (node2.north) -- (node2.north |- node1.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  box/.style={draw},
  dot/.style={minimum size=5pt,inner sep=0pt,fill,circle,node contents={}}
]
\node [box,fill=gray!30] (node1) at (-6,0)    {node1};
\node [box]              (node2) at (-2,-1.5) {node2};
\node [box]              (node3) at (2,-1.5)  {node3};
\node [box]              (node4) at (6,-1.5)  {node4};

\draw (node1.east)  -- (8,0);
\draw (node4.north) -- (node4.north |- node1.east) node[dot];
\draw (node3.north) -- (node3.north |- node1.east) node[dot];
\draw (node2.north) -- (node2.north |- node1.east) node[dot];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `shorten` option to center the circle on the line.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (node1)   at (-6,0)   [draw,fill=gray!30] {node1};
        \node (node2)   at (-2,-1.5)    [draw] {node2};
        \node (node3)   at (2,-1.5) [draw] {node3};
        \node (node4)   at (6,-1.5) [draw] {node4};

        \draw (node cs:name=node1,anchor=east) -- (8,0);
        \draw[-*, shorten >=-2pt] (node cs:name=node4,anchor=north) |- (6,0);
        \draw[-*, shorten >=-2pt] (node cs:name=node3,anchor=north) |- (2,0);
        \draw[-*, shorten >=-2pt] (node cs:name=node2,anchor=north) |- (-2,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Does anyone knows if this solution has been incorporated in tikz/pgf into an pre-defined arrow tip?

Comment: @EduardoAlvesdaSilva Just saw your comment now, by accident. I would guess that if it isn't described in the chapter about arrow tips (I couldn't see it at a quick glance), then it's not part of the package currently. But it's probably not likely that it would be added if no one asks for it ... You can post  a feature request at https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues